# Custom Vision API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, vision-api

I want to count number of people on below image, 
I believe it could be possible with Microsoft vision api or custom vision api but right now I'm not able to login on microsoft cognitive service.

**Can anyone please confirm, Is it possible or not with MS cognitive services ?**
[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can use Face API to count the number of faces.

Comment: Yes, you are right. do you know any other workaround to count number of objects

Answer (score 1):

Counting objects within images is currently not supported for any of the Vision API's provided through Microsoft Cognitive Services.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Answer (score 1):

You can test it on your own using this url - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/ -> Go to 'Recognize celebrities and landmarks'
This is what is the output

```
{
"categories": [
{
  "name": "plant_tree",
  "score": 0.45703125,
  "detail": null
}
],
"adult": null,
"tags": [
{
  "name": "grass",
  "confidence": 0.99937587976455688
},
{
  "name": "field",
  "confidence": 0.94717073440551758
},
{
  "name": "people",
  "confidence": 0.65122932195663452
},
{
  "name": "grassy",
  "confidence": 0.546949565410614
},
{
  "name": "lush",
  "confidence": 0.11115188896656036
}
],
"description": {
"tags": [
  "grass",
  "kite",
  "field",
  "flying",
  "people",
  "grassy",
  "large",
  "soccer",
  "group",
  "man",
  "green",
  "walking",
  "dog",
  "playing",
  "many",
  "hill",
  "woman",
  "blue",
  "standing",
  "crowd",
  "ball"
 ],
 "captions": [
  {
    "text": "a group of people flying kites in a field",
    "confidence": 0.7429714961690741
  }
 ]
 },


 "requestId": "ba0592e6-1449-450e-a00f-a551ed0da4a8",
  "metadata": {
    "width": 160,
    "height": 120,
    "format": "Jpeg"
  },



"faces": [],
  "color": {
    "dominantColorForeground": "Green",
    "dominantColorBackground": "Green",
    "dominantColors": [
      "Green"
    ],
    "accentColor": "718E39",
    "isBWImg": false
  },
  "imageType": {
    "clipArtType": 0,
    "lineDrawingType": 0
  }
}
```

It identifies people with a confidence level of 0.65%

I tried with a more clear image and got the count of people in the form of "faces" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br8xj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Custom Vision API and Computer Vision API both supports object detection functionality now.

If you have an existing dataset or you can label a dataset, then you can use [Custom Vision](https://customvision.ai) to train a model first and then detect similar persons in unseen images. If you are ok with general person detector, which does not need training, then you can use [Computer Vision API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-object-detection).